# What is the correct practice of doing Android APP for Magento ecommerce platform

Tags: android, web-services, magento

Me and my team are starting the dev on Android app for a Magento system.

And appologies if my subject is a bit too broad to answer, allow me to elaborate it as following aspects:

1. Magento offers its API(with Soap and REST), http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html,  so intuitively, we will have Android work with these API directly for requesting or submiting data.  But with some cases, it seems cause very much burden for the APP side to generate or parse data with the Magento API, so should we have some Java or PHP web services as kind of middle layer between the APP and the Magento API. Is this the right way for Magento Android APP development?
2. Magento offers this API based on its original installation, but in many cases, the projects require the Magento to be customized, like install some extension or in some cases write a module or rewrite some existing code. I suppose Magento of course won't generate API for these automatically, how we make API for this part(to be specific, if I write the API for this, where should I Put it and configure it)?

Answer (score 0):

1) It all depends on how you will elaborate your Android app.

1.a - If it is going to support the original features of Magento, and, only using Android app, then stick with their API.

1.b - If you plan to write a similar app for other platforms in the near future, such as iOS or Windows Phone, then, you can easily have an API wrapper in PHP or other server side language of your choice, where, there you document your service layer (app to server/server to app) api calls, as, this will subsequently benefit you in the sense of not having to change all the apps if something changes on the Magento API, as, you are wrapping it up in your own API.

1.c - Restful model is a burden if followed through from scratch, some http verbs such as PUT are blocked by firewalls, so, wrapping those into POST is a common practice.

2) For extensions, modules and customization, your own API wrapper can take care of such differences and decide to do support some or all, or, none, depending on the scenario of your project.

3) Implementing HTTP Calls using traditional AsyncTask is a burden, so, I strongly recommend you adopting some third party libraries such as [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/), [RoboSpice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/) and [RetroFit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to help you managing these requests and the json parsing dilemma!